# Java sort list alphabeticaly with value "Other" at the end

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I got a small Spring Boot application that manages some projects and clients.
A client has a country ( which is an entity) and I want to let the user when he wants to create/update his clients to chose from a predifined country picklist in the UI.
If the country is not present in the list, the user should chose "Other" untill a new country will be added by the admin.
The only problem is that this "Other" value must be always at the end of the pick list and the rest of the countries should be sorted alphabetically. If I sort the list alphabetically the value "Other" will be somewhere at the middle.
How can I manage to do this efficiently (both Java and DB) ?
I am using for now JPA repository findAll for countries.
One first ideea was to add an index to each country and put "Other" with a big value so I will sort by index. But if an insert is done....I dont know how to update the other values.

EDIT:
Jens Schauder Solution worked !

Comment: You can write your own `Comparator` which explicitly checks for "Other" and always returns it being larger than any other value. Once you tried that and run into problems, feel free to come back with questions.

Comment: just wondering, is it bad idea to add **others** into sorted data?

Comment: Came with an idee but I am not sure it works as I am not that good with MySQL : what if I keep the index, all countries have value 1 and "Other" will have 0. Then, the querry will be : order by name asc order by index desc

Comment: How about this ? `select * from country where name <> 'others' order by name
union
select * from country where name  = others'` , here `country` is the table name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a ordering column, I call it `sortorder` for now. Fill it with `0` by default and with `999` for the special "Other" country.

Then order by `sortorder` and country name.

Comment: The OP already suggested this in their question, and as they pointed out, this would mean they need to re-sort everything when they do an insert.

Comment: As Goibniu sayd, that will not work efficiently after an insert is done

Comment: @Goibniu incorrect. The suggestion is just to set the column to `0` for every value apart from "Other" which will be set to `999` and use the column as a secondary orderings. You could event set the value for "Other" to `999` in a trigger.

Comment: @TufisiRadu why? What part of doing an insert makes this complicated? Just insert `0` when the value is not "Other" and `999` when it is. You could even do this with a trigger.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you are right. I managed to do it. Thanks a lot Jens Schauder

Comment: @TufisiRadu You are welcome. The canonical way to say "Thank you" here at SO is to upvote the question and accept it if it was helpful/solved the issue.

Comment: @JensSchauder I upvoted you since I saw your solution worked but : Thanks for feedback! Vote cast by those under 15 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ah, I misunderstood the suggestion, this is a good solution - although the name of the column is misleading ;)

Comment: @JensSchauder Done :D !

Comment: Just curious, is it conceptuly right to have additional column (do data modelling) for our logic purpose?

Answer (score 0):

> Java way

- Remove “other” from list (if the default list contains “other”)
- Sort the List if required (it can be avoided if you fetch from DB in
  a sorted order)
- Add the “other” at end of the list

**Assuming its a simple string based Arraylist**

> DB way

```
Select countryname from countryTable order by  countryname union select  other from dual
```

**Please note syntax nd method will vary depending upon your  choice of DB but the abstract idea remains same**

Comment: Seems unnecessary - not least because removal of items from an `ArrayList` would be `O(n)` per item. Writing a custom `Comparator` would be both simpler and more efficient.

Comment: I knew Java would handle this but is not very eficient. I know that you should always bring only the necesary data from DB and let SQL server to do it.

Comment: This answer is illegible - please learn about [formatting markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Whilst the answer is not a bad one, the lack of readability is likely to attract downvotes. Take some time to make the answer _look_ nice - format the bullets, format the code, etc

Comment: @TufisiRadu eh? What on earth makes you think that?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I just wanted to point out that as long as it is a DB solution Is better to do like that instead of Java.If MySQL can bring me the result I need why shall I use Java? Am I wrong? This is the first reason why I asked here

Comment: @TufisiRadu sadly not that simple. If you have both indexes then the database would probably be faster. If you don't, then it's not so clear-cut.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see. Thanks a lot for all your help :D !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add `isOther` field to your entyty/table and sort by two fields/columns `isOther` then `name`.

Comment: Jens Schauder mentioned it above! Thx a lot anyway !

Answer (score 0):

You can read from database in sorted order and use `union` to add **others** to the resultset, if others also present in table:

```
select * from country where name <> 'others' order by name 
union 
select * from country where name = 'others'
```

if others is **not** present in **table** you would like to add manually (in `mysql`)

```
select * from country order by name
union
select 'others';
```

If you are doing in `java`, why not just add **others** to your `list` in the end, assuming data read from table in `sorted` order.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have got a profession list including "other". I solved this problem using **Comparator**.

This solution is correct for ascending order. Replace "1" with "-1" If you want in descending order.

```
private static final String OTHER_PROFESSION_FIELD_NAME = "Other";
private static final Locale LOCALE = new Locale("tr", "TR"); //Locale

public Comparator<Profession> compareProfessionList() {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(LOCALE);
        return (o1, o2) -> {
            if (o1.getProfession().equals(OTHER_PROFESSION_FIELD_NAME))
                return 1;
            if (o2.getProfession().equals(OTHER_PROFESSION_FIELD_NAME))
                return -1;
            return collator.compare(o1.getProfession(), o2.getProfession());
        };
    }
```